# Objective C - NSDecimalNumber Overflow Exception Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, overflow, nsdecimalnumber

There is a crash in my live app that happened in the following code:

```
- (void)setUpProgressForAmount:(NSDecimalNumber*)amountValue forProgressView:(UIProgressView*)progressView overUnderLabel:(UILabel*)overUnderLabel forTextLabel:(UILabel*)textLabel  {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__
    NSString *amountLeftString = nil;
    NSDecimalNumber *amountLeftValue = [budgetedAmount decimalNumberBySubtracting:amountValue];
    if ([amountLeftValue compare:[NSDecimalNumber zero]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        //make it a positive amount if a negative amount
        amountLeftValue = [[NSDecimalNumber zero] decimalNumberBySubtracting: amountLeftValue];
    }
    amountLeftString = (NSString *)[[[ObjectsHelper sharedManager] currencyFormatter] stringFromNumber:amountLeftValue];

    NSDecimalNumber *amountProgress;
    NSString *overUnderString = nil;
    if ([budgetedAmount compare:[NSDecimalNumber zero]] == NSOrderedDescending) {

        [overUnderLabel setHidden:NO];

        amountProgress = [amountValue decimalNumberByDividingBy:budgetedAmount];

        [progressView setHidden:NO];
        progressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.05];
        progressView.progress = [amountProgress doubleValue];

        if ([amountProgress doubleValue] > 1.0) {
            [progressView setProgressTintColor:[[MyTheme sharedTheme] defaultRedColor]];
            overUnderString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",amountLeftString,NSLocalizedString(@"over", @"over")];
            [overUnderLabel setTextColor:[[MyTheme sharedTheme] defaultRedColor]];
        }
        else {
            [progressView setProgressTintColor:[[MyTheme sharedTheme] defaultGreenColor]];
            overUnderString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",amountLeftString,NSLocalizedString(@"under", @"under")];
            [overUnderLabel setTextColor:[[MyTheme sharedTheme] defaultGreenColor]];
        }
        overUnderLabel.text = overUnderString;
    }
    else {

        [overUnderLabel setHidden:NO];
        [overUnderLabel setText:@""];

        [progressView setHidden:NO];

        progressView.progress = 0;
    }
}
```

It happened in the following line:

```
NSDecimalNumber *amountLeftValue = [budgetedAmount decimalNumberBySubtracting:amountValue];
```

and the reason for the crash was:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSDecimalNumberOverflowException', reason: 'NSDecimalNumber overflow exception'
```

I have never seen this error before, and there is not much documentation on it. I cannot reproduce the error, so far at least.

In the code, budgetedAmount is a NSDecimalNumber as well, set from the return value of one of these methods (I don't know which one in this crash):

```
+ (NSDecimalNumber*)getBudgetAmountDecimalForBudgetAmountNumber:(NSNumber*)amtBudgetedInt canRound:(BOOL)canRound {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__
    NSDecimalNumber *budgetedAmountDecimalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
    if([amtBudgetedInt integerValue] > 0){

        budgetedAmountDecimalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:[amtBudgetedInt integerValue] exponent:(0-[[[ObjectsHelper sharedManager] currencyScale] integerValue]) isNegative:NO];

        if (canRound && [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kRoundAmounts] integerValue] != 0) { //not rounding (rounding is zero)
            budgetedAmountDecimalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[[[ObjectsHelper sharedManager] roundingFormatter] stringFromNumber:budgetedAmountDecimalNumber]];
        }
    }
    return budgetedAmountDecimalNumber;
}

+ (NSArray*)getCalcBudgetAmountCanRound:(BOOL)canRound {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__
    NSDecimalNumber *calcBudgetedAmountDecimalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
    NSInteger calcBudgetedAmountInt = 0;

    for (Person *person in persons) {

            NSNumber *personBudgetNumber = person.amtBudgetedInt;//NSNumber - numberWithInt

            if ([personBudgetNumber integerValue] > 0) {

                calcBudgetedAmountInt += [personBudgetNumber integerValue];
                NSDecimalNumber *personBudget = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:[personBudgetNumber integerValue] exponent:(0-[[[ObjectsHelper sharedManager] currencyScale] integerValue]) isNegative:NO];

                if (canRound && [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kRoundAmounts] integerValue] != 0) {

                    calcBudgetedAmountDecimalNumber = [calcBudgetedAmountDecimalNumber decimalNumberByAdding:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[[[ObjectsHelper sharedManager] roundingFormatter] stringFromNumber:personBudget]]];
                }
                else {
                    calcBudgetedAmountDecimalNumber = [calcBudgetedAmountDecimalNumber decimalNumberByAdding:personBudget];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    NSNumber *calcBudgetedAmountNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:calcBudgetedAmountInt];
    return @[calcBudgetedAmountDecimalNumber,calcBudgetedAmountNumber];
}
```

I know that I could debug this if it were happening on my own device or the simulator, but I am at a loss to do it from the data that I have especially since I have tried to reproduce the  error and can't.

Could someone shed some light on this situation for me, or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Here the relevant portion of the crash report:

```
Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x38d331fc
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSDecimalNumberOverflowException', reason: 'NSDecimalNumber overflow exception'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x2e333f4b __exceptionPreprocess + 131
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x387746af objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                       0x2e333e8d -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
3   Foundation                           0x2ed2c6bd -[NSDecimalNumberHandler exceptionDuringOperation:error:leftOperand:rightOperand:] + 228
4   Foundation                           0x2ed2b715 _checkErrorAndRound + 93
5   Foundation                           0x2ed2b8a1 -[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberBySubtracting:withBehavior:] + 116
6   MyApp                          0x000b2cbb -[MyDetailViewController(Budget) setUpProgressForAmount:forProgressView:overUnderLabel:forTextLabel:] (MyDetailViewController+Budget.m:531)
```

Comment: A single crash? Do you test and limit the input of numbers?

Comment: There can be an unlimited number of people (persons), and they can each have a budget. I don't really know how I can limit that. As far as the budget entered manually, I did test the limits on that and it worked fine. And yes, a single crash. But where this is one, there will likely be more..

Comment: Are you sure the crash is at that line? Looking at the code, I would have guessed it was somewhere else.

Comment: @TomHarrington yes, it is the top line of all the lines in the crash log for my app, and this is the method in the line and this is the number of the line for that method. Where would you have guessed that the crash was?

Comment: I was thinking the call to `decimalNumberByDividingBy:`, which could easily overflow if you're dividing by a small enough number.

Comment: Print the values for local variables just before it crashes please. "budgetAmount" and "amountValue"

Comment: The crash is in a live app. @TomHarrington I did test to make sure that budgetedAmount is greater than zero, but you think that could still be a problem there? I will post some of the crash log above in case that can shed some light.

Comment: If it actually were zero, you'd get a divide by zero error. Very small but not zero could trigger an overflow. But if that's not the right line, that's not the cause.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that wasn't the right line, but it is something good to be aware of. But I'm still confused about the error.. I can test more, but I was wondering if there was something that would jump out as blatantly wrong to more experienced programmers. If not I guess that is good...

Comment: I guess I don't even know - how large *can* a NSDecimalNumber safely get? It is not stored anywhere like a property in a database, just calculated. This error is because the number got too large?